# CKEditor not showing in Angular Boilerplate project

Tags: angular, npm, ckeditor, textarea, boilerplate

I am using CkEditor Standard 4.7.3. My code not display CkEditor instead it shows simple TextArea. Here the below code i've been using.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('myEditor');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divMailBox">
        <span>Subject</span>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="myEditor" name="myEditor" cols="20" rows="10"><b>New Text can this be changed</b></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what to be added

Comment: you need to use angular syntax to show the editor in angular application

Comment: No Need i've found the answer and added below

Answer (score 0):

I've Found an answer Reviewing this url 
https://embed.plnkr.co/hnB0R3/

Please follow these steps 
1) install package 
npm install ng2-ckeditor --save

2) Add Script in index.html

3) in app.module.ts adde below

import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

then add CKEditorModule component in imports section

imports: [

....../* some component */

,CKEditorModule
],

4) then add below control in your html page

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="content" debounce="500">
<p>Hello <strong>world</strong></p>
</ckeditor>
```

5) Run and check the HTML editor in your page.